# Why is my code not working properly (it keeps resulting in the same thing)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

My Money Checking code

```
class MoneyChecker:
type = ""
amount = 100
def checker(self):
    dirty = "The %d %s is a dirty note" % (self.amount, self.type)
    if money1.amount == 200:
        return dirty
    
    clean = "The %d %s is a clean note" % (self.amount, self.type)
    if money2.amount < 200:
        return clean
    else:
        return dirty
money1 = MoneyChecker()
money1.amount = 200
money1.type = "Naira"

money2 = MoneyChecker()
money2.amount = [100][1]
money2.type = "Naira"
print(money1.checker())
print(money2.checker())
```

The code is supposed to result

```
                        "The 200 naira is a dirty note"
                        "The 100 naira is a clean note"
```

But it keeps bringing

```
                        "The 200 naira is a dirty note"  
                        "The 100 naira is a dirty note"
```

Comment: Why do you refer to `money1` and `money2` in the `checker` function?

Comment: Because I had no idea how to make the code work the way I wanted it (assuming if money1 and money2 are variables asking the user for input)? 
Just started python

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statements are the variables of specific instances, you need to use self:

```py
def checker(self):
        dirty = "The %d %s is a dirty note" % (self.amount, self.type)
        if self.amount == 200:
            return dirty
        
        clean = "The %d %s is a clean note" % (self.amount, self.type)
        if self.amount < 200:
            return clean
        else:
            return dirty
```

Note: You could remove the first `if` statement since it is effectively included in the second one:

```py
dirty = "The %d %s is a dirty note" % (self.amount, self.type)
clean = "The %d %s is a clean note" % (self.amount, self.type)

if self.amount < 200:
    return clean
else:
    return dirty
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking instances of your class that are defined as global variables, which most would consider a big no-no. It's much simpler to check the current instance using `self`.  For example try the following.

```
class MoneyChecker:
    type = ""
    amount = 100
    dirty = "The %d %s is a dirty note"
    clean = "The %d %s is a clean note"

    def checker(self):
        output = (self.amount, self.type)
        return self.clean % output if self.amount < 200 else self.dirty % output
    

money1 = MoneyChecker()
money1.type = "Naira"
print(money1.checker())


money2 = MoneyChecker()
money2.amount = 200
print(money2.checker())
```

`self` is simply a variable that references the instance object of the class.  It is automatically passed in as the first parameter in most class method calls.

For example,  `money1.checker()` is roughly the same as `MoneyChecker.checker(money1)` so inside the `checker` method `self` is `money1`  and when you call `money2.checker()`,  `self` is `money2`.

Comment: Can you explain self to me (What it means ?)

Comment: @JimohTemidayo  See the last portion of my answer for explanation.